# Exiting full screen mode in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen

I am working on a flash game, that will be distributed as and EXE file.
I would very much like the game to run full screen, which is not a problem, but I am struggling with replacing flash default behavior when escape is pressed. When escape is pressed I would like to display a custom menu asking the user if they want to exit the game or continue playing, not just exit full screen more.

Is this possible in Flash?

Answer (score 1):

To take control over the reserved keys you will need to use a custom projector like [flashjester](http://www.flashjester.com/) or [mdm's zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/). Using one of those also has the added benefits of being able to change screen resolution and disabling the right click menu.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Adobe AIR to package your flash project. stage.displayState will let you change to full screen without the keyboard restrictions imposed on with the flash player plug-in. The newest beta of AIR 2 will also allow you to package it in an EXE.